# In-sufficent Off-topic flagging options

Tags: bug, off-topic, flagging

It seems that there is a bug with the off-topic flagging as there is only the option to migrate to meta. There should at least be one other option.

This has also been brought up several times since the original post [here](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4120/why-is-there-no-general-off-topic-flag) and [here](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4119/i-was-told-this-question-should-be-migrated-to-dsp)

Here is what I am seeing:

[image]

Comment: It may be that cross-site migration is now limited to moderators. As of today, I still seem to be able to migrate any topic to any SEN site. If you think something belongs elsewhere, just flag it, and we will evaluate and take the appropriate action.

Comment: @jrista I was flagging not voting to close.

Comment: Oh, I see that now...hmm, that is kind of a problem...

Comment: I was going to ask the same thing today, after seeing that "how to survive in the wilderness" question. I tried to flag as off-topic but the only choices were "shopping" and move to meta...

Comment: The question this is linked to is not the same question. This is about flagging and the so called duplicate is about voting, very different. Either reopen this or use my new question (which is a duplicate). http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4120/why-is-there-no-general-off-topic-flag

Comment: Instead choose "other (needs ♦ moderator attention)" rather than flagging as off-topic and it won't go those the standard vote to close logic, which is common between the two.