# I was told this question should be migrated to dsp

Tags: discussion, migration

https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42868/what-is-databending-and-how-does-it-actually-work

I tried to flag it as such, [but there's no option for DSP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjLYu.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just flag it for general moderator attention and put it in the comments.  SE limits it to up to 5 migration sites for automated migration and DSP isn't setup as one of them for us, so the mods have to do it behind the scenes.