# Off-topic Close Reasons

Tags: discussion, site-attributes

See: [What do site moderators need to do to support the new custom question close reasons?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184637/what-do-site-moderators-need-to-do-to-support-the-new-custom-question-close-reas)

Today we have one in active use:

> Questions seeking product or service recommendations are off-topic
>   because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your
>   situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Are there others that make sense? We used to have one about Videography, but this has been deactivated.

I ask because of this: [Why is there no general off-topic flag?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4120/why-is-there-no-general-off-topic-flag?noredirect=1)

Comment: Is it possible to have a "off topic" with custom reason?

Comment: No, not that I know of. This is intended to be frequently encountered reasons.

Comment: Was the off-topic reason about videography banned by SE for some reason, or could we put it back?

Comment: @mattdm - Not that I know of... I can turn it back on.

Comment: That would make me happy. :) See suggested text below....

Comment: I would also like to see something like "and are often more dependent on personal preference than objective expert knowledge" added to the "obsolete quickly" note in the product recommendation close reason....

Comment: Oddly enough, you can't modify the reason after the fact... So, I created a new video one matching your model (as it is the recommended structure), but putting one up requires two moderators to do. I guess they want two fingers on the big red button... :)

Comment: I hope you fixed my missing word "is". :)

Comment: Yep. Appears that I can still edit until it's gone live.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to have

> This question is about video in a context that is not likely to be [relevant to still photography](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/291/).

Answer (score 0):

I feel the need for a "off-topic" with custom reason, but if that's not an option just a generic "off-topic", without a specific reason.

Comment: That _is_ an option for close votes, just not for flagging. You'll have 3000 rep very soon now, so that will be available to you.

Comment: "Very soon" in my case might still be 6+ months (we're picking up our puppy tomorrow), and I can't be the only one using that kind of flag? ;-)

Comment: The moderators are generally reluctant to cast off-topic votes, because those votes count as authoritative and close the question immediately. I don't know if flagging as off-topic puts the question in the close-vote review queue for non-mods at all -- I think it doesn't.